# save copy of existing remote page using php

Tags: php, caching

i'm trying to give a PHP code any URL (e.g. article in newspaper website), and the output that i need that this page content to be saved on mysql to be retrieved anytime with its original content that might be changed if accessing the original URL.

how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the steps of `Joran`. But, I would recommend `curl` over `file_get_contents()`. You can use `curl` like this:

```
$url = 'Your_URL_Here';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

You need to enable `curl` extension if it's not enabled by default. But `curl` is faster and lets you specify any option that you may want.

See [curl manual](http://php.net/curl)

Comment: thanks Sakibmoon for your reply, i did try it with $url = 'www.cnn.com' and did echo $data, and found that CNN page displayed below my URL address.

the question, if i did save $data in a longtext in MySQL, and did retrieve it after a month, will it display same info i'm seeing now, with text and images i see now?

Comment: @George It depends on the availability of the images. Images are saved as link and if CNN doesn't change them(I don't think they will change that), you will see them just the way you see now.

Answer (score 1):

First use `file_get_contents()`, then save it in your database. Set a cron job to check if it's still the same or not, if not save it again.